# MySQL join three queries without multiplying records

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have three tables:

`tblUnits [Unit_ID, Country]`

`tblEvents [Unit_ID, Month, Duration_Hrs]`

`tblMetrics [Unit_ID, Month, Service_Hrs]`

and built 3 queries on them:

1.

```
SELECT Unit_ID
FROM tblUnits
WHERE City = 'NewYork'
```

with output:

```
Unit_ID
1
2
3
```

2. 

```
SELECT
COUNT(IF(Event_Type in ('X', 'Y'), 1, NULL)) as Ev_Count,
SUM(CASE
        WHEN Event_Type in ('X', 'Y') THEN Duration_Hrs
    END) Duration
FROM tblEvents
WHERE
Design = 'GoodDesign'
AND Month = 'May'
AND Unit_ID in (1,2,3)
```

with output:

```
Ev_Count | Duration
1        | 10
```

3. 

```
SELECT SUM(Service_Hrs) as SumSH
FROM tblMetrics
WHERE Month = 'May'
AND Unit_ID in (1,2,3)
```

with output:

```
SumSH
100
```

Now I would like to combine those 3 queries to get output like this:

```
Ev_Count | Duration | SumSH
1        | 10       | 100
```

My query with two left joins multiplies tblEvents and tblMetrics values.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: MySQL server 5.6.34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't join the queries without getting additional rows which will return wrong aggregations and since your version of MySql does not support `CTE`s, you have to use twice the 1st query with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT
  SUM(Event_Type IN ('X', 'Y')) Ev_Count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Event_Type IN ('X', 'Y') THEN Duration_Hrs END) Duration,
  (
    SELECT SUM(Service_Hrs)
    FROM tblMetrics
    WHERE Month = 'May'
    AND Unit_ID IN (SELECT Unit_ID FROM tblUnits WHERE City = 'NewYork')
  ) SumSH
FROM tblEvents
WHERE Design = 'GoodDesign' AND Month = 'May' 
AND Unit_ID IN (SELECT Unit_ID FROM tblUnits WHERE City = 'NewYork')
```

Also, both your aggregated columns `Ev_Count` and `Event_Type` use the condition:

```
Event_Type IN ('X', 'Y')
```

so why don't you filter for this condition in the WHERE clause and avoid conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) Ev_Count,
  SUM(Duration_Hrs) Duration,
  (
    SELECT SUM(Service_Hrs)
    FROM tblMetrics
    WHERE Month = 'May'
    AND Unit_ID IN (SELECT Unit_ID FROM tblUnits WHERE City = 'NewYork')
  ) SumSH
FROM tblEvents
WHERE Design = 'GoodDesign' AND Month = 'May' 
AND Event_Type IN ('X', 'Y')
AND Unit_ID IN (SELECT Unit_ID FROM tblUnits WHERE City = 'NewYork')
```

Comment: when I try to add one more column 'SUM(Period_Hrs)' to the SumSH subquery I get an error "operand should contain 1 column". Does it mean I need to add another subquery to select next column? Then I would have to use 1st query 3 times.

Comment: This code works if the subquery returns only 1 column. For more columns you need a CROSS JOIN.